# Insert generic template to Eclipse by keyword trigger

Tags: eclipse, triggers

Is there any build in function inside eclipse that allows you to preset certain generic text/code template for later use by trigger a certain keyword?

Lets say I have a boilerplate of html which I always use. So the next time I want to use it, I only want to do something like "..html5template" which would trigger the preset template.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have any HTML editor installed into my Eclipse instance, but most text editors support defining templates (e.g. in case of Java editors you could visit the **General**/**Java**/**Editor**/**Templates** preference page), and there such templates can be defined, that could be inserted using content assist with a selected keyword.

So I would open the preferences dialog, and search for a page named Template or Templates.